# Convert curl command into python code

Tags: python, json, curl

```
curl -v -d "api_key=kkkk&api_secret=ssss&endpoint=eeee&app=aaaa&params=[{"money":"1111", "last":"0.045"}, {"money": "1111", "last":"0.05"}]... > 500 records" http://my_server:port/api/process/json
```

this one should be converted into python script, as the mine goal is these json parts {"money":"...", "last":"...."} to have more than 500 diferents money values. And all of them to be passed at the end to the server.

I've tried several different ways, even asking here for help for some steps, but never succeed to reach the final expected result.
 So what I've tried:

```
cog = []
for i in range(20201, 20705):
cog.append('{"money": str(i), "last": "0.001"}')
params = tuple(cog)
p_c = {}
p_c['api_key'] = 'kkkk' 
p_c['api_secret'] = 'ssss'
p_c['app'] = 'aaaa'
p_c['endpoint'] = 'eeee'
p_c['params'] = json.dumps(params)

req1 = requests.post_simple(url=Server.My_server, params=p_c)
```

This one is passing the params as "money": str(i)
    http://my_server:port/api/process/json?api_key=kkkk&api_secret=ssss&endpoint=eeee&app=aaa&params=[{"money": str(i)...................

I had another option that I tried (trying to find it now) where it was messing up the order of the params, making some keys values of other keys

Also tried:

```
p_c = {}
p_c['api_key'] = 'kkkk' 
p_c['api_secret'] = 'ssss'
p_c['app'] = 'aaaa'
p_c['endpoint'] = 'eeee'

params = '{"money":"11111","last":"0.0001"},'
for i in range(20201, 20705):
    params = params + '{"money":"%d","last":"0.0001"},' % i
dat = ("params="+params)
req1 = requests.post_simple(url=Server.my_server,params=p_c, data=dat, headers=headers)
```

The expected pass call to the server should looks like:

```
http://my_server:port/api/process/json?api_key=kkkk&api_secret=ssss&endpoint=eeee&app=aaa&params=[{"money": "1111", "last": "0.0001"}, {"money":"22222", "last":"0.00001"},.... ,{more than 500},........]
```

Comment: *"This one is messing up the order of the cogs, making some keys values of other keys"*. Could you explain that? It seems like the first snippet should do what you're looking for (once you fix the indentation of the `for` loop).

Comment: "This one is messing up the order of the params"
It should be params.
What I mean is that when everything is passed to the call links looks like 
    .....params=[{"money":"last", "money":"last},{"1111":"0.001","2222":"0.001"}......]

I am totally not sure how to fix the loop in order to pass the Key:value in correct order

Comment: Well, in addition to indenting the `cog.append(...)` line, you also need to remove the single quotes. But that wouldn't cause the issue you're describing, and I'm not sure what would. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: if i dont remove the '' just checked, it is passing the params as : "money": str(i), not even messing up the key:value

Comment: Correct, that's why you need to remove them. And, again, indent that line.

Comment: Why are you double-encoding your parameters? Pass a *list of dictionaries* to `json.dumps()`.

Comment: @gilbdud u were right, it is passing correctly when i remove the quotas, but still something in the call is not correct, because the server is not sending back the expected json reponse

Martijn Not so sure, it was answer to other my question. Now i removed the converting in tupple and the result is the same. I need them to be in dictionarry in order to pass them to the call, it doesnt pass a string

Comment: Not sure where the `requests.post_simple` method is coming from; it is not part of the standard `requests` package. And note that `curl -d` sends the data as the body of a POST, so the URL will *not* contain a `?...` query parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are double-encoding your `params` parameter:

```
cog = []
for i in range(20201, 20705):
    cog.append('{"money": str(i), "last": "0.001"}')
params = tuple(cog)
...
p_c['params'] = json.dumps(params)
```

You encoded a sequence of strings, while your original `curl` command contains a JSON list with JSON objects (dictionaries in Python). The `tuple()` call is entirely redundant, both tuples and lists are converted to the same JSON construct.

Build dictionaries:

```
cog = []
for i in range(20201, 20705):
    cog.append({"money": i, "last": "0.001"})
...
p_c['params'] = json.dumps(cog)
```

You can do so in one line with a list comprehension:

```
cog = [{"money": i, "last": "0.001"} for i in range(20201, 20705)]
...
p_c['params'] = json.dumps(params)
```

Note that the `-d` switch to `curl` sends that data as the *body of a `POST` request*, so make sure you send the parameters as such with the `data` argument:

```
req1 = requests.post(url=Server.My_server, data=p_c)
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!! It worked. And more important, for first time with this issue now i understand what i am doing